# Positioning the Element with respect to another Element in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have to position my tooltip according to the button how to write CSS for positioning the tooltip with respect button.

```
<body>
<div id="root">
  <button onMouseOver={showTooltip}>
    click me
  </button>
</div>

<div className="tooltip">
  <div className="tooltip-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
  </div>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: could you please share your complete code? The css and js files as well. Apart from that, if you are using react you can use reactstrap/ react-bootstrap tooltips

Answer (score 0):

Make an anchor element (`position:relative`). Then, add your tooltip (`position:aboslute;top: ....; left: ...;`) and adjust it accordingly.

```css
.container {position:relative;background: yellow; border:2px solid black;padding:30px;}
.tooltip {position:absolute;top:25px;left:30px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button onMouseOver={showTooltip}>
    click me
  </button>
  
  <div class="tooltip">
    <div class="tooltip-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Relative movement to sibling or another element is NOT possible. The element to be adjusted has to be a child of anchor-element. That's the way its done in CSS.